# Getting error while fetching data from json file using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am getting the following error while fetching data from my json file.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
    at Object.parse (native)
    at uc (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:15:480)
    at Zb (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:82:229)
    at http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:83:143
    at m (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:7:322)
    at cd (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:83:125)
    at d (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:84:380)
    at http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:118:334
    at n.$eval (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:132:452)
    at n.$digest (http://localhost/json/angularjs.js:129:4
```

Here is my code:

```
var test=angular.module('testapp', []);
test.controller('HelloController',function ($scope,$http) {
    console.log('hello');

    $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'data.json',
         headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
     }).then(function successCallback(response){

     },function errorCallback(response) {
        //$state.go('/',{}, { reload: true }); 
     });
  // Do something with myService
});
```

data.json:

```
[
{
    'id':1,
    'email':'abc@gmail.com',
    'name':'Rahul'
    },
    {
    'id':2,
    'email':'def@gmail.com',
    'name':'Ram'
    },
    {
    'id':3,
    'email':'ghi@gmail.com',
    'name':'praveen'
    }
]
```

How can I get all the data?

Comment: Try using double-quotes, ", in your JSON instead of single-quotes, '.

Comment: i did as per you..still there is error.

Comment: Is it the same error? As @whistling_marmot noted the first error seems to be because of single quotes. Try removing the headers object from the `$http` call, as you're not POST-ing anything.

Comment: yes error is same.its one path error i think.When i did `/data.json` this error is not coming but can not get the proper file.When i did again `projectfoldername/data.json` again wrong path is also coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular code is ok. The problem is in data.json file, use `"` not `'`.

data.json:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "email":"abc@gmail.com",
    "name":"Rahul"
    },
    {
    "id":2,
    "email":"def@gmail.com",
    "name":"Ram"
    },
    {
    "id":3,
    "email":"ghi@gmail.com",
    "name":"praveen"
    }
]
```

You can see the code running on http://plnkr.co/edit/LjrqDMolGoaQn96ds6fv?p=preview

Comment: @whistling_marmot already said this in his comment to the original message.